# running a script in Oracle application express SQL Scripts results in an error, but runs fine when ran in SQL command and SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dml

I get this error with this script (shown below) when I run it in oracle application express SQL Scripts, but not if ran in SQL command section of application express or in SQL Developer.  Is there an explanation as to why?

ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH

```
UPDATE (SELECT w.bay_caseflow_sku_count, 
           CASE WHEN combined_layer_qty <= 0 
       AND bay_activity > 0 
       AND adjusted_bay_USPD * day_count <= bay_activity * caseflow_uspd_max THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 END AS new_bay, 
           w.bulk_caseflow_sku_count, 
           CASE WHEN combined_layer_qty <= 0 
       AND bulk_activity > 0 
       AND adjusted_bulk_USPD * day_count <= bulk_activity * caseflow_uspd_max THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 END AS new_bulk, 
           w.combined_caseflow_sku_count, 
           CASE WHEN combined_layer_qty <= 0 
       AND adjusted_combined_USPD <= caseflow_uspd_max THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 END AS new_combined 
      FROM extract_work_001 w 
           INNER JOIN control_records c 
              ON w.loc_id = c.loc_id 
     WHERE w.combined_layer_qty = 0) t 
SET bay_caseflow_sku_count = new_bay, 
   BULK_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT = NEW_BULK, 
   COMBINED_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT = NEW_COMBINED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, though I can't find anything similar on MOS. The ORA-20001 error code means it's an application-defined error, so APEX seems to be parsing the statement, and perhaps has a case-sensitivity problem.

If I create a dummy table called `t42` then entering a simple command with the same structure as yours gets the same error:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM T42)
SET X = NULL

ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH
```

If I change *just* the `SELECT` to `select` then it works:

```
UPDATE (select * FROM T42)
SET X = NULL

0 row(s) updated. 0.02 seconds
```

Running your exact statement also gets the `ORA-20001`; again just changing `SELECT` to `select` gets past that, and I get `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` instead, which is reasonable as I don't have your tables defined.

This is on a test workspace at https://apex.oracle.com. I can only guess APEX is parsing the script before attempting to execute it, but exactly what it's doing under the hood is a mystery. Not a very satisfactory explanation but at least there seems to be a workaround...

Comment: Thanks man, that worked.  That is quite odd.  I have a series of 70 scripts, and only two formatted like the example didn't work.  
Thanks again